# Triggering contextual error message for inputs

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I'm developing on a intranet application in HTML5 with XHR (I can't give access to any example). You can see a test [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bz88V/).

For a `<form>` I wish to make an XHR, I test the validity of the form like this:

```
if (form.checkValidity())
{
    $.post([...]);
} else {
    errormessages();
}
```

Same way, into the return of the post (the `[...]` part), I can have error validating messages from the server. So I attach them to the inpts like this:

```
input.setCustomValidity(le_error_message);
```

`le_error_message` is really attached as I can see into `input.validationMessage`.
The `:invalid` css selector is set to the input but...

How can I trigger the browser (firefox, chrome, etc...) to display their standard contextual error-message?

I tried `form.submit()`, but it will really submit the form, even skipping what I wish the browser should do.

I can't see any reference to that, nor into inspecting `input` and `form` elements.

See also this [French speaking paper](http://dascritch.net/post/2012/02/21/Validations-complexes-de-HTML5-farcies-au-Javascript).

Comment: What do you mean by the 'standard contextual error-message '?

Answer (score 0):

You want to display "server side form errors" with the default "client side form error display" functionality ? but if your form is valid client-side , it will not display any error message at all. If you want to display error caught server-side , build your own error display functionality with javascript , since you are using ajax.

Comment: This is not really helpful feedback IMHO. What he is trying to do is a pretty clever and potentially useful way to use the HTML5 form validation mechanism also for server-side validation errors. There is no obvious reasons why it should *not* be possible to re-use the setCustomValidity() method in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that it would be nice if this were possible. Did the idea get discussed in the HTML5 working group? One might for example add a form.showValidityErrors() method scripts could trigger at will.

What you're trying to do in the [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/bz88V/) is however not supposed to work. The browser is supposed to do validation and show validation messages (including the custom ones) *before* the submit event fires. Calling setCustomValidity() from a submit event has no effect. You should move the code to the keypress/change listener like [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bz88V/5/).